# How do true and false cross in the update method?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
private Vector3 upVector;
    private Vector3 rightVector;
    private Vector3 downVector;
    private Vector3 leftVector;

    private float speed = 3f;

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject ball;

    private bool isUp, isDown, isRight, isLeft = false;

    private void Awake()
    {
        upVector = Vector3.up * speed;
        rightVector = Vector3.right * speed;
        downVector = Vector3.down * speed;
        leftVector = Vector3.left * speed;
        MusicOperator.instance.musicPlay(MusicOperator.instance.musics[1], true);
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (isUp)
        {
            ball.transform.position += downVector * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
            Debug.Log(isUp);
        }
        else if (isDown)
        {
            ball.transform.position += upVector * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
            Debug.Log(isUp);
        }
        else if (isLeft)
        {
            ball.transform.position += rightVector * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        }
        else if (isRight)
            ball.transform.position += leftVector * Time.fixedDeltaTime;

    }

    public void MouseDown()
    {
        isUp = isDown = isLeft = isRight = false;

        if (this.name == "Up")
        {
            ball.transform.position += upVector;
            isUp = true;
        }
        else if (this.name == "Down")
        {
            ball.transform.position += downVector;
            isDown = true;
        }
        else if (this.name == "Right")
        {
            ball.transform.position += rightVector;
            isRight = true;
        }
        else if (this.name == "Left")
        {
            ball.transform.position += leftVector;
            isLeft = true;
        }
    }
```

I have four buttons.(named left, right, up, and down) And all buttons have OnClick event,MouseDown.
I want the ball to go in the direction I clicked first and then the opposite direction.

When I click only up button, it moves up and then goes down, and Debug.Log says only true.
But when I click up button and then down button, the Debug.Log says true->false->true->false->...
Also, the ball stops. I think it is going up and down very quickly, so it looks stopped. I can't understand this.

Comment: Consider adding labels to your debugs to make them more meaningful. eg. `Debug.Log($"Up: {isUp}")`.  Otherwise you lose context and debugging is much more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

## Regarding the issue

I guess the issue occurs because there's a typo in the Down button name, so it sets all the variables to `false` but does not set `isDown` true. You can check it easily by adding something like `Debug.Log("Down button press detected")` inside the `if (this.name == "Down")` block.

If it prints to the console, then you've caught a kind of magic. Otherwise, there's a typo. I'd also suggest to add `else` statement in the if-else chain that prints something like: `Debug.Log("Undefined button pressed: " + this.name)`, for cases of limited values expectation.

## Typos

Also, I am afraid that you have another typo in your code, for example:

```
if (isUp)
{
    ball.transform.position += downVector * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    Debug.Log(isUp);
}
else if (isDown)
{
    ball.transform.position += upVector * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    Debug.Log(isUp); // Here must be isDown value
}
```

Also, that's more crucial to provide context in logs. For example,

```
Debug.Log($"Up event: {isUp}")
```

To catch either your code executed well and in a proper way.